# Do real software have kernel modules inside them on Linux and other OSes

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I like to ask: do applications like Apache Webserver on Linux, Wireshark, and software like network tools and other real world applications that have to do work with network connection, do they need kernel module, If no then is it to what extent a normal practice that applications do have kernel module. Like when I install some application then kernel module installs with it. I know when I enable IIS server from windows, specific kernel module do get enabled that does IIS work. (don't know why that OS does not implement raw sockets api so developer can use)

My question: Some time ago I was trying to make tcp server using raw socket and found that it was something not that easy since kernel does all sorts of things like (correct me if I am wrong)

Checking for spoofed packets

adding its own headers info inside packets

So I am about to Make an application that does following things in kernel

1. Configuring NIC card like reading card registers and reporting back
2. shutting down Network Interface
3. Starting Network interface
4. Reading packets from DMA RX and reporting average number of packets received to detect DOS attacks and if detects DOS then shutting down specific Interface/ like reporting counter for packets

And the Application will just act as a command controller. Like a user can use the application to make changes specified in above 4 points.

So I like to ask you is it common practice for applications to have a kernel module and why this is a resorted option if someone like to choose embedded kernel module in applications,

Above things are for learning purposes.

Comment: It's not very common as far as I know, but things like [DPDK](https://www.dpdk.org/) do exist (which handles network devices in user space, partly by having its own friendly modules in the kernel to allow it to control the network HW). For what you want a raw IP or packet socket will probably work. See also libraries like [libpcap](https://www.tcpdump.org/) (or [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) for Windows) for existing solutions to portable packet capturing and injection. If you don't want to check the packet contents, you can just reads the interface stats.

Comment: @Hasturkun what is `HW` is it stands for hardware

Comment: @Hasturkun Doesn't Npcap also installs driver (Does it ask user to install driver -- If not then why). How does it handle raw sockets or packets reading. windows is like a black-box you can't see anything inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Linux programs very rarely have kernel modules. Kernel modules are normally for hardware device drivers.

If a program does need a certain kernel module, it will tell you to install the module yourself. It won't include a copy of the module.

It sounds like you want to make your own driver that replaces the normal driver for your network card. It's possible, but nobody does it. If you want to shut down or start up a network interface, there is already a way to do that without writing your own kernel module. If you want to count the packets, there's already a way to do that. If you want to see all the packets, there's already a way to do that.

There's no way to read card registers already - that's because every card has different registers. But whatever you want to do *with* those registers, there's probably a way to do it already.